# Prevent fieldset from resizing contents

Tags: html, css, display, fieldset

I tried to resize my `<fieldset>` element, but it automatically made its contents smaller. Then, I added `display:inline-block` in my CSS file (as suggested by many answers on a similar topic). However, this doesn't help at all, everything stays the same. What should I do? I'd like a noob-friendly solution, since I'm not that good at CSS, as you may have noticed. Cheers!

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: white;
  width: 40%;
}

legend {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>XXX</legend>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use percentage on the content's width, it will will change according to the width of the container(fieldset).

Just remove the percentage value.

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: white;

}

legend {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}

label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

input[type=text] {

  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>XXX</legend>
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username">
</fieldset>
```